# C# полноэкранное приложение со своим разрешением

Tags: c#

Подскажите в каком направлении двигаться, штатные методы вроде фулскрин и убрать бордеры не тот случай. В идеале сделать полноэранное приложение со своим разрешением под любой экран как в играх и с большим количеством форм внутри него.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По честному только через DirectX, но стоит учесть что он не любит внутри себя виндовые формочки.

Comment: А как-же OpenGL? @cpp_user

Comment: Если OGL транслируется через DX то возможно иначе эмуляция полноэкранного режима: окно без бордеров и заголовков на весь экран поверх всех окон например как это сделано в GLUT.

Comment: Проблема не в том чтобы сделать во весь экран и поверх всех окон, данную штука я реализовал ещё давно и штатными методами, загвоздка только в разрешении при заходе в приложении, если использовать "ChangeDisplaySettings" меняет полностью системное, даже если отлавливать вход и выход из приложения будут лаги и иконки "прыгают" по рабочему столу. Вот и ищу можно ли обойти всё это. Т.е. создать приложение с внутренним разрешением на весь экран с формами внутри или окнами которые можно перетаскивать и похожими на виндовые. @cpp_user

Comment: Я ж и говорю что только DirectX позволяет перейти приложению в так называемый EXCLUSIVE_MODE и делать вход\выход таким образом что лагов системы не будет видно.

Answer (score 3):

Для изменения разрешения существует функция [ChangeDisplaySettings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/dd183411.aspx). Перечисляются режимы с помощью [EnumDisplayDevices](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/dd162609.aspx). Вы можете воспользоваться интеропом, чтобы вызвать эти функции в управляемом коде.

Если вас интересуют игры, то у DirectX свои методы для изменения разрешения. В принципе ими можно пользоваться и по отдельности, если очень хочется.

Comment: Меня интересует только "разрешение как в играх" в остальном ничего не нужно. По поводу ChangeDisplaySettings, если не ошибаюсь и я с этим как-то работал, то оно меняет именно системное разрешение, а не устанавливает его для запущенного приложения. @Discord